# In MongoDB's native NodeJS Driver, when to use MongoClient constructor and when to use the Db constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The MongoClient and Db constructors are described in the [manual](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/contents.html). When should you use one and when should you use the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoClient should normally be preferred, the only major issue is that it is newer (1.2+).

Let us quote [the manual:](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html)

> **MongoClient or how to connect in a new and better way**
>
> From driver version 1.2 we introduce a new connection Class that has
> the same name across all our official drivers. This is to ensure that
> we present a recognizable front for all our API’s. This does not mean
> that your existing application will break, but rather that we
> encourage you to use the new connection api to simplify your
> application development.
>
> Furthermore, **we are making the new connection class MongoClient acknowledges all writes to MongoDB, in contrast to the existing connection class Db that has acknowledgements turned off.**

The two biggest changes are thus the fact MongoClient acknowledges all writes to DB and when the actual database is chosen in the connection.

With MongoClient:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb"); // The DB is set here

  mongoClient.close();
});
```

vs with Db:

```
// db is selected in the next line, unlike with MongoClient and most drivers to other databases
var db = new Db('test', new Server('locahost', 27017)); 
// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  db.on('close', test.done.bind(test));
  db.close();
});
```